# Should notification badges and labels match?

Tags: badge

Example: If the badge in the app's tab bar is red in color, when a user goes to that screen, should the corresponding label be the same color? Or does it not matter?
[image: Example]

Comment: Who are your primary users? Are they younger 'Gen Z' users, or millennials using the app for work? What is your business model? Is this a social network app, or something like a gas station's companion app, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

## It doesn't matter

Think about this: you may have different types of badges (maybe you don't, but most systems do). However, notifications are unique. **You won't have a notification color for each type of badge.** Furthermore, most systems won't even have a special badge for a **new** item; they will simply display the new item and that's it.

**A perfect example is the site you're posting your question on** *(especially noticeable when there are moderation actions required or when there's an answer to a user question, as you'll see after I post this answer)*.

All the above being said, if your only notification is for **new** items and you plan to use a badge, maybe it's a good idea to connect them using the same color. But again: it's not required at all (and you'll probably need to test this extensively).